# “These stuff” vs. “this stuff”

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, determiners, singular-they

I wrote “I know all *these* stuff; I don’t have to go over *them* again” in my writing-exam paper and the teacher corrected it to read, “I know all *this* stuff; I don’t have to go over *it* again.”

The teacher is Irish so I don’t think he would make a mistake but I think even if the first one (*these*) was wrong, the second one (*them*) should have stayed the same. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Stuff* is singular, so it needs to be preceded by the singular demonstrative determiner *this*. For the same reason, it needs to be referred to by the singular pronoun *it* and not the plural pronoun *them*.

Comment: Thank you.. So when I say "all this stuff" stuff stays singular Even though the meaning is pulural. Am I correct?

Comment: *Stuff* is an uncountable, or mass, noun, and such nouns are grammatically singular.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: could it be "that stuff" as in, "I know that stuff pretty well." That sounds correct to my ear but I realize it could just be colloquial/slang.