# Do you write "here is some stuff" or "here are some stuff"?

Tags: grammar

I am new here so sorry if this question has been asked before.

Which one is correct "here is some stuff" or "here are some stuff" ?

Comment: Stuff is a mass noun, so always construed with a singular verb.

Comment: You can use the search facility to check wether a question has been asked before or not.

Comment: In this case, a search for `stuff is are` returns [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88062/these-stuff-vs-this-stuff) as its first result.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the help. I'll definitely search before posting a question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Stuff* is an uncountable noun and should be used with *is* and not *are*.